# Why can't I delete the default AWS security group?

Tags: firewalls, amazon, aws

There are no inbound nor outbound rules. It's an empty group. What use does it serve?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *default security group* is created when a VPC is created.

By default, it allows ALL traffic from instances that belong to that security group and all incoming traffic. The fact that your default group doesn't have any rule suggests that you deleted the rule.

AWS doesn't allow deleting *default security group* because many API call/CLI command allow omitting the security group, so AWS needs a *default security group* to place instances with an unassigned security group.

See [Default security group for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup) in the VPC documentation.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Once upon a time there were no VPCs (EC2-Classic). I suppose the default security group exists to support those applications.